# Rename the files with date appended in MacOs

Tags: file-management, macos

I want to append the date in the file name. I have seen many batch file script. Is there any software available for that?

Comment: Question is unclear in the sense of which date do you want to append. I it a set of existing files and you want to append the current date, the last accessed date, the creation date, the ... You said "I have seen many batch file script", why not use one of these?

Comment: Last accessed date. I want some software, or some detailed information about these batch file script, such as how to run them... etc.

Comment: Without knowing something / example of "these batch file script" it is hard to say anything. How something works is off-topic here. maybe good to ,take the [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn [Help](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make 2 of the files (or more) you can use the rename option on the mac and select adding date to file name.  Select both your files and right click on them. You'll grt a panel like the one shown below.

[image]

Click on the option to "rename n items". This gives you the window shown below.

[image]

As you can see in the image the Name Format is set to Name and Date. This option appends the date to the file name.